# S3 : Download Multiple Files in local git-bash console

Tags: amazon-s3, git-bash

I have multiple files in S3 bucket like

- file1.txt
- file2.txt
- file3.txt
- another-file1.txt
- another-file1.txt
- another-file1.txt

now, I want to download first 3 files, name startwith "file*", How can i download from aws s3 in local git-bash console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply you can download with below command :

```
aws s3 cp --recursive s3://bucket-name/ /local-destination-folder/ --exclude "*" --include "file*"
```

Comment: git bash giving an error , bash aws command not found

Comment: first you need to install aws command and configure aws credentials then try